# spring boot file upload on 1.5.9 always returns null file object

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am trying for file upload in spring boot i searched a lot of options in stackoveroverflow still it ends me with null file object

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fileUpload",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@ModelAttribute("file")MultipartFile file)
```

what's going wrong in this
I tried to upload yaml file with restClient/postman file as option without any header content/multipart data

Comment: did you try including multipartResolver as a bean? Have a look here
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Define a request parameter for your file and a [MultiPartFile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html). Now you can post your file with Postman. In the body of your request define a key with the name "file" (your request parameter) and as the value select your file.

```
@PostMapping("fileUpload")
    public void upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        fileService.writeFile(file);
}
```